# how to custom display inside textformfield flutter as multiselect search?

Tags: flutter, multi-select, flutter-textformfield

I have a textformfield for search like the image below. i am looking forward to when i select 1 result below. An item that will look like `Iteam 0` above will be added inside the textformfield. then I can search and select many times like that. does anyone have any solution for this problem?

[This is my UI now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxTBm.png)

Comment: share some piece of code for better understanding